# How to assert a monkey patch was called in pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

Consider the following:

```
class MockResponse:
    status_code = 200

    @staticmethod
    def json():
        return {'key': 'value'}
                                  # where api_session is a fixture
def test_api_session_get(monkeypatch, api_session) -> None:
    def mock_get(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse()

    monkeypatch.setattr(requests.Session, 'get', mock_get)
    response = api_session.get('endpoint/') # My wrapper around requests.Session
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {'key': 'value'}
    monkeypatch.assert_called_with(
        'endpoint/',
        headers={
            'user-agent': 'blah',
        },
    )
```

How can I assert that the `get` I am patching gets called with `'/endpoint'` and `headers`? When I run the test now I get the following failure message:

`FAILED test/utility/test_api_session.py::test_api_session_get - AttributeError: 'MonkeyPatch' object has no attribute 'assert_called_with'`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks to all those of who reply in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a `Mock` object to call `assert_called_with` - `monkeypatch` does not provide that out of the box. You can use `unittest.mock.patch` with `side_effect` instead to achieve this:

```py
from unittest import mock
import requests

...

@mock.patch('requests.Session.get')
def test_api_session_get(mocked, api_session) -> None:
    def mock_get(*args, **kwargs):
        return MockResponse()

    mocked.side_effect = mock_get
    response = api_session.get('endpoint/') 
    ...
    mocked.assert_called_with(
        'endpoint/',
        headers={
            'user-agent': 'blah',
        },
    )
```

Using `side_effect` is needed to still get a mock object (`mocked` in this case, of type `MagickMock`), instead of just setting your own object in `patch`, otherwise you won't be able to use the `assert_called_...` methods.

*To clarify*: when I write "*monkeypatch does not provide that out of the box*" this is related to the usage of the `assert_called...` methods. It does not imply that you can't use monkeypatch to implement a similar functionality, as is nicely shown in the answer by Tommy.

Answer (score 16):

Going to add another response that uses monkeypatch rather than "you can't use monkeypatch"

Since python has closures, here is my poor man's way of doing such things with monkeypatch:

```
patch_called = False

def _fake_delete(keyname):
    nonlocal patch_called
    patch_called = True
    assert ...

monkeypatch.setattr("mymodule._delete", _fake_delete)
res = client.delete(f"/.../{delmeid}"). # this is a flask client
assert res.status_code == 200
assert patch_called
```

In your case, since we are doing similar things with patching an HTTP servers method handler, you could do something like (not saying this is pretty):

```
param_called = None

def _fake_delete(param):
    nonlocal param_called
    patch_called = param
    assert ...

monkeypatch.setattr("mymodule._delete", _fake_delete)
res = client.delete(f"/.../{delmeid}")
assert res.status_code == 200
assert param_called == "whatever this should be"
```